# Misleading cmd prompt message

Tags: windows, command-line, terminal

this is not that critical, but since it has been bugging me for 2 years now, I'll ask.

I am a programmer, and I'm running a Grails compiler in Windows Command Prompt. When I need to terminate a process in cmd, I hit <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>. It will prompt me a confirmation message saying "`Terminate Batch Job (Y/N)`". There are times I just pressed those keys, but will change my mind, so I will choose to cancel the termination of the batch job. But it will always terminate even if I choose "N". In fact, it will terminate both on any character!!

Here is the screen shoot:
[image]

It also happened when I try to stop other batches. I'm wondering what has happened. Some sort of virus, maybe?

Comment: Is `grails` an exe or another batch or other script?

Comment: Its `grails.bat`

Comment: Hmm. I've never seen this problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to comments grails is a script and I think that it calls some executable.
When you pressing Ctrl+C you killing executable and command intepreter asks you about execution the rest of the script.
Regardles of answer it is not possible to continue killed executable.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comments, you are running `grails.bat` which then likely launches another `.exe` (let say `grails.exe`).  I suspect that both the shell (`cmd.exe` which parses and executes the `grails.bat` script) and your executable (`grails.exe`) are being interrupted with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> keyboard combination.  The shell prompts you if you want to cancel, whereas the executable just exits.  Once the process has exited the batch program then completes normally, which is why you can not continue even though you are prompted.