# Windows cmd terminate batch job when type N

Tags: cmd.exe, language

Angular ng serve command is working.. I click unfortunately ctrl+c then I click N
but batch exit why?

```
webpack: Compiled successfully.
    ^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)?
    Terminate batch job (Y/N)? N
    D:\2017\rijo\nodejs\angularCLI>
```

Comment: "I click unfortunately ctrl+c then I click N but batch exit why?" - Because you had already cancelled the script.

Comment: Okay then why batch is asking "Terminate batch job (Y/N)?"

Comment: If N it should not be terminated thats right? then why its terminated

Comment: Not if you cancel the script with that shortcut.  What happened was supposed to happen.

Comment: I want to rerun the command it will take more time

Comment: Don't use that shortcut if you want to rerun the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1091397/234916), CTRL+C always kills the executable that is currently running in the batch script. The prompt then asks if you want to continue running the rest of the script. So if you answer 'Y', it moves onto the next step in the script, but if 'N' it exits the batch completely. Therefore if your batch is already on the last step, it will appear as if answering 'N' has no effect because there are no more steps to run.